# Unable to get attendance data of employees from biometric devices using cloud based windows services even if services is running correctly

Tags: c#, sdk, windows-services, cloud, biometrics

This is small portion of window service code for fetching real-time attendance data from Biometric Device from cloud. Service is working but unable to get data from Device.This service is taking data from device and storing inside project folder making .log files.But when punched the card on device i get nothing.i am confusion on app.config files.There is local host(127.0.0.1:8080) as server in sdk of manufacturer which i got(but they are saying this is cloud based sdk).What should be  server list in this case? Please help me.I am totally new in this WebSocketServer.

> private void webSocketServer_NewMessageReceived(WebSocketSession session, string message) this method is used for registering new devices but this is not firing when i punched card to device.I am not pasting all codes here within this method.

```
 using SuperWebSocket;
 using SuperSocket.SocketBase;        
 public class WebSocketLoader
    {
        private static WebSocketServer webSocketServer;

        public static Dictionary<string, string> _registeredDevices;


        private WebSocketLoader(IWorkItem server)
        {
            var wsServer = server as WebSocketServer;
            webSocketServer = wsServer;
        }
        public static WebSocketSession GetSessionByID(string sn)
        {
            if (_registeredDevices.ContainsKey(sn))
            {
                return  webSocketServer.GetAppSessionByID(_registeredDevices[sn]);
            }
            else
                return null;
        }

        public static void Setup(IWorkItem server)
        {
            var webSocketLoader = new WebSocketLoader(server);
            webSocketLoader.AddNewMessageReceived();
            webSocketLoader.AddNewSessionConnected();
            webSocketLoader.AddSessionClosed();
            _registeredDevices = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            _registeredDevices.Clear();
        }
        public void AddNewMessageReceived()
        {
            webSocketServer.NewMessageReceived += new SessionHandler<WebSocketSession, string>(webSocketServer_NewMessageReceived);
        }
        public void AddNewSessionConnected()
        {
            webSocketServer.NewSessionConnected += new SessionHandler<WebSocketSession>(webSocketServer_NewSessionConnected);
        }

        private void webSocketServer_NewSessionConnected(WebSocketSession session)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(webSocketServer.GetAllSessions().Count());
            LogHelper.Receive("NewConnected[" + session.RemoteEndPoint + "]");
        }

        private void webSocketServer_SessionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseReason reason)
        {
            LogHelper.Receive("Closed[" + session.RemoteEndPoint + "],Reason:" + reason);

        }

        private void webSocketServer_NewMessageReceived(WebSocketSession session, string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(webSocketServer.GetAllSessions().Count());
            LogHelper.Receive("MessageReceived[" + session.RemoteEndPoint + "],Message:" + message);
        }
    }
```

App.config file contains following line 
`<RedisConfig WriteServerList="127.0.0.1:8080" ReadServerList="127.0.0.1:8080" MaxWritePoolSize="10000" MaxReadPoolSize="10000" DB="1" AutoStart="true" LocalCacheTime="180" RecordeLog="false">`

Comment: I'm using the same SDK and im getting null session and the session is not getting connected instead it gets closed and getting the response Recv:<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
[2023-11-16 ][Info]Closed[LOCAL IP],Reason:ClientClosing
is there anyway you could help me
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

127.0.0.1 meant for localhost. You need to update a valid IP and PORT in the biometric machine. Then if you use that IP & Port your code may work. Make sure the machine is connected in the same network.

In general, biometric machines can be not be associated with the public IP. Hence, TCP/IP communication with the machines installed in the remote location can not be done through cloud application.

For cloud communication from biometric machine, web api supported biometric machines can be used.

Comment: I'm using the same SDK and im getting null session and the session is not getting connected instead it gets closed and getting the response Recv:<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
[2023-11-16 ][Info]Closed[LOCAL IP],Reason:ClientClosing
is there anyway you could help me
Thanks